# Не выделяется элемент TreeViewItem при IsSelected = true

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Есть проводник который сделан с помощью TreeView. 
Задача: найти в TreeView заданную папку и выделить её.
Разметка TreeView:

```cs
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Name="catalog" Margin="5" 
      TreeViewItem.Expanded="catalogExpanded" TreeViewItem.Selected="getFolder">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="scan" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Name="img"  Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Fill"
                            Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=Header,
                            Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Так заполняется TreeView

```cs
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    item = new TreeViewItem()
    {
        Tag = drive,
        Header = drive.ToString().Substring(0, 2)
    };
    item.Items.Add("*");
    catalog.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Ну и соответственно при раскрытии узла

```cs
private void catalogExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
    if (item != null && item.Items != null)
    {
        try
        {
            item.Items.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }

    DirectoryInfo dir;
    if (item.Tag is DriveInfo)
    {
        DriveInfo drive = (DriveInfo)item.Tag;
        dir = drive.RootDirectory;
    }
    else dir = (DirectoryInfo)item.Tag;
    try
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
            newItem.Tag = subDir;
            newItem.Header = subDir.ToString();
            newItem.Items.Add("*");
            item.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Необходимая папка задаётся переменной `string dir;`, когда нужно её найти, то используются следующие методы:

```cs
private void findDir()
{
    string[] pathItems = dir.Split('\\');
    string pathNode = pathItems[0];
    ItemCollection items = catalog.Items;
    foreach(TreeViewItem node in items)
    {
        if (node.Header.Equals(pathNode))
        {
            if (pathItems.Length == 1) node.IsSelected = true;
            else
            {
                node.IsExpanded = true;
                findDir(node, 1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void findDir(TreeViewItem node, int index)
{
    string[] pathItems = dir.Split('\\');
    string pathNode = pathItems[index];
    ItemCollection items = node.Items;
    foreach (TreeViewItem subNode in items)
    {
        if (subNode.Header.Equals(pathNode))
        {
            index++;
            if (index >= pathItems.Length)
            {
                subNode.IsSelected = true;
                return;
            }
            subNode.IsExpanded = true;
            findDir(subNode, index);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

И всё работает, но необходимая папка не выделается :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Справа картинка как хотелось бы (и как это работает если кликать мышью). Слева то что происходит в реальности.

P.S. Только сейчас увидел, что необходимая папка таки имеет выделение на левой картинке, но оно такое бледное, что заметить его очень тяжело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было всего лишь перевести фокус на само дерево.
Например так:

```cs
private void findDir()
{
    string[] pathItems = dir.Split('\\');
    string pathNode = pathItems[0];
    ItemCollection items = catalog.Items;
    catalog.Focus();      // Например тут
    foreach(TreeViewItem node in items)
    {
        if (node.Header.Equals(pathNode))
        {
            if (pathItems.Length == 1) node.IsSelected = true;
            else
            {
                node.IsExpanded = true;
                findDir(node, 1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```